# Cypress API request - errors for not a function

Tags: cypress

I'm struggling to find the expected syntax for an OKTA 'List users with a search' Cypress API request.

```
url: 'https://companydomain/api/v1/users/?search=profile.lastName eq'`${searchTerm}`,
url: 'https://companydomain/api/v1/users/?search=profile.lastName eq "autotest"',
```

The example above with the jquery variable fails for profile.lastName eq" is not a function.
The hard-coded example with "autotest" succeeds. I've tried several different ways, but can't seem to add a variable within that API.
Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

String interpolation in JS looks like this:

```js
url: `https://companydomain/api/v1/users/?search=profile.lastName eq "${searchTerm}"`,
```

You have to have backticks around the whole string.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That worked! I'll note that for future use.